# Complex (at least for me) MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I haven't been able to figure out any way to handle this, without making two separate database queries and figured I would turn here to see if what I'm trying to achieve is possible.

I have two database tables:

```
messages
--------
...
media ==> Boolean representing if the message has attached media

messagesMedia
-------------
...
messagesID ==> Reference to message
```

Is there a way to get a query to join all associated media, if `media = 1` and just return the messages if `media = 0`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for that. You will get all messages record irrespective of there is a match in `messagesMedia` table and in case there is a match, you will get the matched record as well.

```
select m.*, mm.*
from messages m
left join messagesMedia mm on m.messagesID = mm.messagesID;
```